# INNER JOIN DISTINCT with MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, inner-join

I have a mysql problem. I have two tables like this that I need to join together.

table:

> id otherid2
>       1 | 1
>       2 | 1
>       3 | 2
>       4 | 2

table2:

> otherid otherid2
>      1 | 1
>      2 | 1
>      3 | 2
>      4 | 2

I'm using:

```
SELECT id,otherid FROM table INNER JOIN table2 ON table.otherid2=table2.otherid2
```

This gives me:

> id otherid
>      1 | 1
>      1 | 2
>      2 | 1
>      2 | 2
>      3 | 3
>      3 | 4
>      4 | 3
>      4 | 4

As you can see I get duplicates of id as there is otherid2s that is not unique in table2. What I need is to INNER JOIN DISTINCT in some way, I only want the result to be as below. Not duplicates.

This is what I want:

> id otherid
>      1 | 1
>      2 | 1
>      3 | 3
>      4 | 3

Can I do this in an easy way?

Comment: What is your basis to decide as to which rows from the join to discard? For eg? for Id 4, there were 2 rows with otherid's 3 and 4. On what basis did u discard row with otherid 4 and select the row with otherid = 3?

Comment: I don't see how you get 3|3 or 4|3 unless there are values not being shown in the first two tables.  Also, I don't see how you get 2|2 based on what you are showing here.

Comment: Try to play with subqueries (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html). Not very optimal, but quite efficient.

Comment: @InSane: I want the row with the lowest id in table2.

Comment: @James Black - But that is what I get when I run the query in mysql. id is primary key in table and otherid is primary key in table2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the row with the lowest id in table2, this should probably do it

```
SELECT id, min(otherid)
FROM table 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table.otherid2=table2.otherid2
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks! I must be very tired today.. :)

Comment: @Martin - Agree :-) When you miss something like that, its time to go home!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your comment you wanted the lowest, then I'd suggest a group by and a min aggregator

```
SELECT id, MIN(otherid) AS otherid ... GROUP BY id
```